# Print from file after writing java

Tags: java, file-io

I've tried finding the answer to this but I couldn't through searching a couple different things. Please excuse me if I don't format something correctly, this is my first post here.

So I'm writing a program in java that basically will keep a record of the user's rock climbing history on different routes and difficulties.

I am encountering a problem with writing to a text file (I'm still new to `FileIO`) where after writing to the file, the new information that is written won't be printed until after I exit the program and restart it. Here is the program, the method in question is `writer()`:

```
public class Climb {
    private String name;
    private char type;
    private double rating;
    private char subRating;
    private String loc;
    private int tries;


    public Climb(){}

    public Climb(String name, char type, double rating, char subRating, String loc, int tries) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.subRating = subRating;
        this.loc = loc;
        this.tries = tries;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public char getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(char type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public double getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(double rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getLoc() {
        return loc;
    }

    public void setLoc(String loc) {
        this.loc = loc;
    }

    public int getTries() {
        return tries;
    }

    public void setTries(int tries) {
        this.tries = tries;
    }

    public char getSubRating() {
        return subRating;
    }

    public void setSubRating(char subRating) {
        this.subRating = subRating;
    }

    public static String header (){
        return String.format("%-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s","Name","Type","Rating","Location","Attempts");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String tempRating = Double.toString(rating) + subRating;
        return String.format("%-10s %-10s %-10.5s %-10s %-10s %n", name, type, tempRating, loc, tries);
    }
}

public class ClimbTracker {
    /*
     * prints a formatted output of an array of Climb objects
     */
    public static void printRecord (Climb[] c) {
        try {
            System.out.println(Climb.header());
            for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
                System.out.print(c[i].toString());
            }
        }
        catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /*
     * Creates a new array of Climb objects from a file and return the array.
     * Number of objects in file doesn't need to be known
     */
    public static Climb[] objFromFile (File fn){
        try {
            Scanner file = new Scanner(fn);
            ArrayList<Climb> climbsArray = new ArrayList<>();
            Climb[] climbObjArray;
            while (file.hasNext()) {
                // name, type, rating, subRating, location, tries
                String name = file.next();
                char type = file.next().charAt(0);
                String temp = file.next();
                char subRating;
                double rating;
                /*
                 * This if block is to deal with the problem that climbing
                 * ratings are often something like "5.12a", so it splits it
                 * into a double and a char as rating and subRating respectively
                 */
                if (temp.length() > 3){
                    subRating = temp.charAt((temp.length() -1));
                    temp = temp.substring(0, temp.length()  -1);
                    rating = Double.parseDouble(temp);
                } else {
                    rating = Double.parseDouble(temp);
                    subRating = ' ';
                }
                String loc = file.next();
                int tries = file.nextInt();
                Climb climb1 = new Climb(name,type,rating,subRating,loc,tries);
                climbsArray.add(climb1);
            }
            climbObjArray = new Climb[climbsArray.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < climbsArray.size(); i++) {
                climbObjArray[i] = climbsArray.get(i);
            }
            return climbObjArray;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println("Error " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    /*
     * Will write new climbs to the file
     */
    public static void writer (File fn, Scanner input){
        try {
            FileOutputStream fn_stream = new FileOutputStream(fn,true);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fn_stream);
            System.out.print("Name of route: ");
            out.print(input.next() + " ");
            System.out.print("(B)ouldering or (t)oprope: ");
            out.print(input.next().charAt(0) + " ");
            System.out.print("Rating: ");
            out.print(input.next() + " ");
            System.out.print("Location of route: ");
            out.print(input.next() + " ");
            System.out.print("Number of attempts: ");
            out.print(input.next() + "\n");
            out.flush();
            fn_stream.flush();
            out.close();
            fn_stream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            objFromFile(fn);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File fn = new File("climbs.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Climb[] c = objFromFile(fn);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
            System.out.println("(P)rint recent climbs");
            System.out.println("(W)rite others");
            System.out.println("(E)xit");
            char option = input.next().charAt(0);
            switch (option){
                case 'p':
                    printRecord(c);
                    break;
                case 'w':
                    writer(fn, input);
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("That isn't an option");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The method in the finally block reads the file and creates an `ArrayList` of objects and then stores it in an array of objects for printing and other stuff.

I don't think that should be the problem since it is using the same file object. Unless I need to recreate the file object after writing?

Comment: You have to show the source of `objFromFile()` as well

Comment: Alright I have added in the `objFromFile()` method as well.

Comment: I tried running and debugging your code with a dummy `Climb` class with do-nothing constructor and it all seems to work: input is outputted to standard output in a timely fashion and output to the file is there in time for `objFromFile(File)` to read it successfully. Could you please be more specific about what is not working in the above code?

Comment: Sure, so in the main method I have an infinite loop that asks the user if they want to print out the list of climbs, write a new one, or exit. If I use the write function, it writes to the file correctly after the changes are made. But, when using the print function, only the changes that were written before the program was ever run are shown to the console, instead of including the newly added changes. Only once I exit the program and rerun it and use the print function will the changes be shown to the console. If needed I can provide the rest of the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the array you are printing (when choosing from the menu) is the one in `main` which is `Climb[] c`, while the one get loaded/refreshed after `writer()` is being called is another one it's located in `objFromFile()` so you are loading into an array, and printing another one `Climb[] climbObjArray`.

so i suggest you remove the `finally` block, and call `objFromFile()` in your `main` in the case that matcher `write` so the array in `main` is updated, thus will be printed correctly when user selects function`print`

1- remove this block from `writer()`

```
finally {
    objFromFile(fn);
}
```

2- update `case 'w'` as following:

```
case 'w':
    writer(fn, input);
    c = objFromFile(fn); // <--- add this
    break;
```

now when `case 'p'` is matched, calling `printRecord(c);` will pass updated `c`.

**PS:** a better apprach to convert `ArrayList` into array is using `toArray()` instead of the for loop

```
climbObjArray = climbsArray.toArray(new Climb[climbsArray.size()]);
```

replace the for loop and array `climbObjArray` initialization with above line